# How to show a new worksheet after it's been added?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro button on a sheet (*Line Item Summary*) that creates a copy of *Costing Sheet* as a new worksheet. After the macro is done the active sheet is *Line Item Summary* but I would like it to be the sheet that was created. Here is the macro for the button:

```
Sub NewSheet()

Call Sheet7.NewLine

Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Costing Sheet")
ActiveSheet.Range("B6:F68").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B6:F68").Value

End Sub
```

I was looking into using "Application or Activate" as a way to do this but being fairly new to VBA I'm not sure how or if there's a better way to execute this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In general, you want to [avoid using activate and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code.

Comment: Try `Worksheets(Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Index+1).Activate` right after `Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Costing Sheet")`

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `ActiveSheet.Range("B6:F68").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B6:F68").Value`? *Formulas > Data*? If so, the point above ^ is very valid, good practice is to reference the sheet by (code)name. Therefor, you won't need it to be the *ActiveSheet*

Comment: Anyways, you can interact with the range of another worksheet doing something like `Worksheets("nameofthatworksheet").Range("rangeAddress"). You don't need it to be the ActiveSheet

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns adding the extra line you initially mentioned worked great! Thank you for the feedback

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thank you for the feedback, I will keep this in mind for future reference

Comment: @JvdV thank you for the input. To answer your question, the `ActiveSheet` line of code is used after the new sheet is created to copy and paste range B6:F68 as values only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`Worksheets(Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Index+1).Activate`

right after line

```
Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Costing Sheet")
```

Worksheets can be referenced by their name, codename or index. In your case, line `Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Costing Sheet")` is copying the worksheet `Costing Sheet` right after itself.

So in my code, the part that says `Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Index` will return the index of that worksheet, and we sum up 1 to get right the next one.

**UPDATE**: As I said in comments, sometimes you don't need a worksheet to be the active one to make some operations. In your case, because you want to convert formulas into values, you can do it with a single line. Your final code can be:

```
Sub NewSheet()

Call Sheet7.NewLine

Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Costing Sheet")
With Worksheets(Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Index+1)
    .Range("B6:F68").Value = .Range("B6:F68").Value
End With


End Sub
```